# How may I create this limacon graph (rolling circles included) in LaTex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, animations

I cannot find an example of how to create [this limacon graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lima%C3%A7on#/media/File:EpitrochoidIn1.gif) (rolling circles included) in LaTeX. Could you please help me?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\newif\iftikzepitrochoidhasxis
\tikzepitrochoidhasxistrue
\tikzset{pics/epitrochoid/.style={code={%
  \tikzset{epitrochoid/.cd,#1}
  \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/epitrochoid/##1}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mymax}{2*max(abs(\pv{r}),abs(\pv{d}))+abs(\pv{R})+0.5}
  \iftikzepitrochoidhasxis
   \draw[-stealth] (-\mymax,0) -- (\mymax,0) node[below left]{$x$};
   \draw[-stealth] (0,-\mymax) -- (0,\mymax) node[below left]{$y$};
  \else 
   \path (-\mymax,-\mymax) rectangle (\mymax,\mymax);
  \fi 
  \draw[blue,semithick] circle[radius=\pv{R}];
  \draw[semithick] ({deg(\pv{t})}:{abs(\pv{r})+abs(\pv{R})}) coordinate (c) circle[radius=\pv{r}];
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\itest{(\pv{t}>0?1:0)}
  \ifnum\itest=1
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\isamples}{5+2*(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*int(\pv{t})}
   \draw[red,thick] plot[smooth,samples=\isamples,domain=0:\pv{t},variable=\t,smooth]
    ({(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*cos(deg(\t))-\pv{d}*cos((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*deg(\t)/\pv{r})},
     {(\pv{R}+\pv{r})*sin(deg(\t))-\pv{d}*sin((\pv{R}+\pv{r})*deg(\t)/\pv{r})})
     node[circle,inner sep=1.2pt,fill](e){};
    \draw  (c) node[circle,inner sep=1.2pt,fill]{}  -- (e); 
   \fi
}},
epitrochoid/.cd,R/.initial=3,r/.initial=1,d/.initial=0.5,t/.initial=1,
    axis/.is if=tikzepitrochoidhasxis,axis/.default=true}
\begin{document}
\foreach \Time in {0,0.1,...,6.2}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
 \pic{epitrochoid={t=\Time}};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. A big thanks and have a great 2021!

Comment: What I find difficult to identify or modify is the limacon equation e.g. if I would like to change the limacon equation to r = 2 + cos(θ), what should I modify on the above code?

Comment: @John This `pic` takes some parameters such as the inner radius, `R`, the outer radius, `r`, and the distance `d`, in the same parametrization as Wikipedia does. So you can use e.g. `\pic{epitrochoid={t=\Time,R=2,r=1,d=2/3}};`. If you really want to change the equation (rather than the parameters), you need to modify the definition of the `\pic`.

Comment: @232027.Great. Many thanks!

Comment: @232027. Is it possible to replace the cartesian with polar axes in lines 10 and 11?

Comment: @John This is a separate question. The answer is yes, you can use a `polaraxis` from `pgfplots` unless you want to code the polar axis yourself.

Comment: @232027.I am reading a tikz manual now of how to do it, however, I have just a few experience with LaTex. In the pgfplots package, it seems one has to use a command which declares simultaneously polar axis together with the graph function of interest, something that cannot apply on the above code (lines 10 and 11). I would be really grateful if you can help me on this (last wish). In any case, my best wishes!